# Minimum and maximum number from user input

Tags: c#

How can I limit the user input to 8 and the minimum by 1 on the choose planet code block?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Choose a planet
    Console.WriteLine("Choose a planet number (1 - Mercury / 2 - Venus / 3 - Earth / 4 - Mars / 5 - Jupiter / 6 - Saturn / 7 - Uranus / 8 - Neptune): ");
    int planet = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    // Your Age
    Console.WriteLine("How old are you?");
    int userAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

I tried using length but since it's an int I can't use it.

Comment: [C# Limit textbox to number or letter only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/216600/c-limit-textbox-to-number-or-letter-only), but you will have to do a small change to that example....

Comment: What do you want to happen when the user enters an invalid value?

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy with the function `Int32.TryParse(string input, out var res)`, check the value and show a message to the user that he or she has entered an invalid planet number like in the code below

```
 Console.WriteLine("Choose a planet number (1 - Mercury / 2 - Venus / 3 - Earth / 4 - Mars / 5 - Jupiter / 6 - Saturn / 7 - Uranus / 8 - Neptune): ");
 string choice = Console.ReadLine();
 if(Int32.TryParse(choice, out var planet){
   //the input is a number, check if its less than 1 or greater than 8
     if(planet<1 || planet>8){
       Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid planet number");
     }else{
       //the planet number is valid, TODO code
     }
  }else{
   //the user entered a non integer literal
    Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a number, lets give it one more try");
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
planet = Math.Max(1, Math.Min(planet, 8));
```

This forces the value to be 8 if the user enters a number > 8 and forces the value to be 1 if the user enters a number < 1

Comment: If I'm a dumb user and enter "10", this would operate as if I entered "8". Maybe this is what the OP expects, but this isn't the UX _I_ would expect.

Comment: No, it's not great UX but it answers the very simple question of how to limit a number to the given range.